# How can I find an output of this function's inverse without graphing?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

How can I find $f^{-1}(5)$ where $$f(x)=\frac{27}{\pi}x + \sin x$$ algebraically? Thank you!!

Comment: In general, unless there's a specific thing happening, inverting things that look like $ax + b \sin x$ cannot be done analytically. But in this case, one can guess and check some simple values like $\pi/2, \pi/3, \pi/4, \pi/6$.

Comment: Along with T.Bongers, one notes that it is very difficult to find the complex solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

From
$$
f(x)=\frac{27}{\pi}x + \sin x,\quad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$ we get
$$
f'(x)=\frac{27}\pi+\cos x>0,\quad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$ the function $f$ is then **strictly increasing** over $\mathbb{R}$, observing that
$$
f\left(\frac\pi6\right)=\frac{27}\pi\times\frac\pi6+\frac12=\frac{10}2=5
$$ gives

> $$
> f^{-1}(5)=\frac\pi6
> $$

(without graphing).